# Value Error: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'create'

Tags: python, django

I was in the process of making a create gallery image field in Django for my project, but when I try to access the url, I'm getting a `Field 'id' expected a number but got 'create'.` error. And on postman, I'm getting a `{ detail: "Method \"POST\" not allowed." }`.

```py
class Gallery(models.Model):
    SUBTLEPBR = "subtle"
    AMULET = "amulet" 
    F8THFULPBR = "f8thfulpbr" 

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    screenshot_by = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    image = WEBPField(
        verbose_name=('Image'),
        upload_to=image_folder,
        default="placeholder.png"
    )
    
    PACKS = [
        (SUBTLEPBR, 'SubtlePBR'),
        (AMULET, 'Amulet'),
        (F8THFULPBR, 'F8thfulPBR'),
    ]
    pack = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=PACKS)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Screenshot by "+  self.screenshot_by + " | " + self.pack
```

```py
@api_view(["POST"])
@permission_classes([IsAdminUser])
def createGalleryImage(request):
    user = request.user
    gallery = Gallery.objects.create(
        user = user,
        screenshot_by = "John Doe",
        pack = Gallery.SUBTLEPBR,
    )

    serializer = GallerySerializer(gallery, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/users/login/', views.MyTokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),

    path('', views.getRoutes, name='routes'),

    path("gallery/", views.GalleryImages, name="gallery"),
    path("gallery/<str:pk>/", views.getGalleryImage, name="gallery-image"),
    path("gallery/delete/<str:pk>/", views.deleteGalleryImage, name="gallery-delete"),
    path("gallery/create/", views.createGalleryImage, name="gallery-create"),

    path("updates/", views.PackUpdatesPage, name="updates"),

    path("faq/", views.FaqPage, name="faq"),

    path("subtle-roadmap/", views.SubtleRoadmapPage, name="subtle-roadmap"),
    path("amulet-roadmap/", views.AmuletRoadmapPage, name="amulet-roadmap"),

    path('admin/users/profile/', views.getUserProfile, name="user-profile")
]
```

[image: postman]

The output that is supposed to happen is

```json
{
    "id": 51,
    "screenshot_by": "Person",
    "image": "/placeholder.png",
    "pack": "subtle",
    "user": 1
}
```

(added entire urls code to include entirety of paths)

Comment: Share all the paths.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/er0cLSQP coudn't fit entirety in the comment

Answer (score 0):

This will "fire" the wrong view. Indeed, if you use `/gallery/create`, it will fire `getGalleryImage` with `create` as `pk`.

If the primary keys are integers, you can restrict these with:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('gallery/<int:pk>/', views.getGalleryImage, name='gallery-image'),
    path(
        'gallery/delete/<int:pk>/',
        views.deleteGalleryImage,
        name='gallery-delete',
    ),
    path('gallery/create/', views.createGalleryImage, name='gallery-create'),
    # …
]
```

This will then only "fire" if `pk` is a sequence of digits, like `1425`, not `create`.